# Selection in Notes Client not working (using Eclipse SWT)

Tags: eclipse, swt, lotus-notes

I would like to create a sidebar in the IBM Notes Client which shows infos about an Email. Therefore I use the Eclipse Framework with SWT. The current Code looks like this:

```
package DisplayPlugin;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.NotesUIElement;
import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.NotesUIWorkspace;
import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.documents.NotesUIDocument;
import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.views.NotesUIDocumentEntry;
import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.views.NotesUIView;
import com.ibm.notes.java.ui.views.NotesUIViewEntryCollection;

public class ShelfView extends ViewPart   {

   public static final String ID = ShelfView.class.getName();

   private Label label;

   private ISelectionListener _listener = new ISelectionListener() {
       public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcePart, ISelection selection) {
           NotesUIWorkspace ws = new NotesUIWorkspace();            
           NotesUIElement elem = ws.getCurrentElement();

           if (elem instanceof NotesUIView) {
               NotesUIView currentView = (NotesUIView) elem;
               NotesUIViewEntryCollection collection = currentView.getActionableEntries();
               Iterator docIterator = collection.documentIterator();

               String txt = "";
               while (docIterator.hasNext()) {
                   NotesUIDocumentEntry entry = (NotesUIDocumentEntry) docIterator.next();
                   for (int i = 0; i < entry.getColumnValues().size(); ++i) {
                       txt = txt + i + ": " + entry.getColumnValueString(i) + "\n";
                   }
                   txt = txt + "UNID: " + entry.getDocumentData().getUnid() + "\nURL: " + entry.getDocumentData().getEditUrl() + "\n";                  
               }

               label.setText(txt);
               label.pack();
           }
       }
   };

   public ShelfView()
   {
   } 

   public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
   {    
       Composite comp = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
       comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
       label = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE );
       label.setText("Start...");

       getViewSite().getPage().addPostSelectionListener(_listener);
   }

   public void setFocus()
   {
   } 
}
```

The problem lies in the line: **`NotesUIElement elem = ws.getCurrentElement();`**

When you test the ViewPart in the Notes Client and mark a mail from the list, not the current entry is shown in the sidebar but the mail entry which has been marked **before**.

The following picture shows the IBM Notes Client with the sidebar.

[image]